# Clearing a text box in c#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a way to clear the 'Result (txtBoxResult.Text)' text box if the user made any chances to any other other text boxes? Example: Let's say that after clicking submit I get my result and then I went on any of the other text boxes and added or deleted a number. How could I make the result go away right that moment?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event called `TextChanged`.

First, create an event handler to handle this event:

```
private void TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    txtBoxResult.Text = "";
}
```

Next, subscribe to the event in the form's constructor:

```
txtBoxOp1.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
txtBoxOp2.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
txtBoxOperator.TextChanged += TextBoxTextChanged;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sweeper!

Answer (score 1):

In the other TextBoxes add TextChanged events that clear the original TextBox. Psuedo code:

```
txtBoxOps1.TextChanged += ClearOriginalTextBox;
```

...

```
void ClearOriginalTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtBoxResult.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

In form closing event don't for get to unsubscribe the events:

```
  txtBoxOps1.TextChanged -= ClearOriginalTextBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that can be easier, simply when the user click on the *Submit Buttom* you have to freeze the *textboxs*, so the user can't modify the textboxs again.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: That is definitely something that I will make use of in the future, as for this particular task I actually wanted to keep modifying the texts and clearing the result the moment I had any changes. Thanks